# Many member functions with the same structure in C++

Tags: c++, class, member

Suppose I have a class:

```
class A {

protected:

  vector<double> p1;
  vector<double> p2;
  ...
  vector<double> pn;

public:

//Constructors and destructor
  void SetP1( int, double );
  void SetP2( int, double );
  ...
  void SetPn( int, double );
```

};

Where the structure of all setter's definitions is the same. I am not glad to see this copy-paste here. Is there a `C++`'s style to get rid of this?

Comment: A map? A `std::array` of vectors?

Comment: Can you make the `vector<double>`s an N-sized array?

Comment: That would be a bad idea, but if you want *exactly* this interface, you have to use x-macro trick (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) or write that code manually.

Comment: Yes, just don't have setters at all, make the vectors public,  and factor out the body into a free function if it's not trivial.

Comment: @NirFriedman Protected members are basically public anyway. There's no encapsulation there

Comment: @KABoissonneault How are protected members basically public?  You can't access them like public variables.

Comment: @NathanOliver - You just have to inherit from A and return a reference to the fields you wish to modify directly. Protected fields are really more of a "more cumbersome to access" public fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class A {
public:
  enum {count = 55};
protected:
  std::array<std::vector<double>, count> p;
public:

//Constructors and destructor
  template<std::size_t N>
  void SetP( std::size_t x, double d ) {
    static_assert( N<count, "out of bounds" );
    // I assume we want auto-resize:
    if (x >= p[N].size()) p[N].resize(x+1);
    p[N][x] = d;
  }
};
```

Use:

```
A a;
a.SetP<22>( 7, 3.14 );
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4d97f2176484bb2).

Answer (score 4):

There is, in fact, a way. It removes the repetition, anyway, but I still think having so many setters is a sign of a design flaw.

```
class A {
  static const int n = /*user-defined*/;
  std::array<std::vector<double>, n> p;

  template<int i, std::enable_if_t<i < n, int> = 0>
  void SetP(int j, double d) {
    // example code, no error handling;
    p[i][j] = d;
  }
};
```

Code that uses the class would be written as follows:

```
A a;
a.SetP<0>(2, 3.0);
```

And the SFINAE trick ensures `i` can only be used in range. You can also `static_assert` like François Andrieux suggested in a comment.

Comment: You can `static_assert` that `i < n`.

Comment: Consider using `size_t n` and `size_t i` in this case.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - I recall a discussion from somewhere about the merits of signed vs unsigned integers for indexing, that left me turning to `int` by default, though the details are foggy in my mind. Since Yakk already shows it in his answer, I won't repeat it again. Thanks for both suggestions you gave.

Comment: I am working with objects that can be contain many different parameters. That's why I have so many setters. What could you recommend me in this case? I know it depends on the context but anyway.

Comment: @Wolfgang - Like you said it's hard to say what's best without knowing your requirements. But the reason I think those setters are a false prophet is because the fields are protected. You clearly intend to inherit from A and access the fields directly in the sub-class, which would allow for modification without going through the setters.